# how to share image and text without creating Facebook id from ios

Tags: ios, facebook, image, text, share

How to share images & text to Facebook without creating Facebook id in ios?
I am using slcompose But it is showing "cant be share to Facebook .please try after sometimes"

Comment: Can you show the code you're using and maybe a screenshot of the error you receive?

Comment: - (IBAction)ActionFacebook:(id)sender {
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLogin"])
    {
        [self checkForLoginPermissionInSharing];
        return;
    }
    [self callFacebookMethod];
}

Comment: -(void)callFacebookMethod
{

    
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])){
        
        SLComposeViewController* objSLComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [objSLComposeViewController setInitialText:title];
        .......}}

Comment: if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) condition always false